# Change Featured Image size on Wordpress with a theme activated

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-featured-image

so I have bought a theme from superbThemes. And in this theme you have a news feed with featured images. And my problem is that the featured images are cropped in a horrible way and I can't find a way how to make them appear in a more normal manner. The Theme is called "Newspaperly Premimum"
Here is a example:
[That's the way how it shows up in the News feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBNP.png)
[And that's the way it shows up after you click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSH0V.png)

Please help me...

I tried in Wordpress to change in the settings under media to change the thumbnail size but nothing happened. Then I tried to change the featured pictures size itself to a similar size that the thumbnail would be so that it would at least show the whole picture but that didn't work and it somehow got scaled back up to a minimum of 400x400 pixels (my picture was 400x250)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.